# Sending data stream in sync with video

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a project where I'm streaming a video on a topic using [web_video_server](http://ros.org/wiki/web_video_server) package using webm vp8. On the processing side in my project I have shapes' coordinates that I want to send to my web page on which the video will be streamed that they will be overlay it. I want these shapes to overlay the video and be in sync. The problem is I can't figure out a proper way to send this data (coordinates of the shapes), the stream to the webpage, and have them in sync. Overlaying the video is not a problem I have solved it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202989/sending-data-stream-in-sync-with-video/) by [Nassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21622/nassar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no encoded ROS timestamp sent over the compressed video stream so it would be hard to properly synchronize. Is it possible to do the overlay server side and stream the entire image?

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0